# Let $0<b<1$ and $f_n(x)=x_n$ defined on $[0,b]$. Show that $f_n\to0$ uniformly on $[0,b]$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

Let $0<b<1$ and $f_n(x)=x_n$ defined on $[0,b]$. Show that $f_n\to0$ uniformly on $[0,b]$.

I tried almost everything to prove the statement. I tried to construct a sequence $x_{n_k}$ which is convergent (so Cauchy) as $x_n$ is bounded on $[0,b]$ and to apply uniform continuity of $f_n$ but I can't conclude the proof. If someone could give a hint, I would really appreciate it. Thank you in advance.

Comment: $x_n$ or $x^n$?

Comment: Definitely makes sense, but with $x^n$ instead.

Comment: I don't remember where I found this problem, but probably I misstyped it in my pdf... If it is $x^n$, yes it makes sense. But if it is $x_n$ does it work? When i was doing the probleme the condiiton of $0<b<1$ didn't  really appear helpful to prove the statement. Is it false?

Comment: I found the source of the statement, it is $x_n$

Comment: What is the meaning of $x_n$?

Comment: Here is the link for the exercice (8.1.2): [link](https://math.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Analysis/Book%3A_Real_Analysis_(Boman_and_Rogers)/08%3A_Back_to_Power_Series/8.01%3A_Uniform_Convergence)

Comment: $x_n$ is definitely a typo. If you check the hint, they use $x^n$.

Comment: @Desperado Alright, thank you very much! Sorry for confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f_n(x)=x^n$, then $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \sup_{x\in [0,b]} |f_n(x)-0|=\lim_{n\to \infty}b^n=0,$$ since $0<b<1$.

EDIT: If $b\ge 1$, then $\lim_{n\to \infty}b^n\neq 0$ and the convergence is not uniform.